# Trouble with calling a function with parameters with Taquito

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, taquito

I'm trying to use taquito to call a method in my contract. Note my contract was programmed in SmartPy (if that makes any difference).

I am able to call contract.storage() without any problem.

When I try to call 
contract.methods.mint(wallet,amount).send({ fee: 30000, gasLimit: 200000 })

I get a 400 bad request. 
zone-evergreen.js:2828 POST https://carthagenet.smartpy.io/chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/forge/operations 400 (Bad Request)

The contract is deployed here: https://better-call.dev/carthage/KT1WvmH3BSawQyKy2mEfTvxvAuTSLSAtotAc/operations

[image: Console error of call]

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was setting the private key incorrectly.. 
I change to..

```
      Tezos.setProvider({rpc: environment.network});
      Tezos.importKey(environment.inMemorySigner);
```

and all worked ok!